# Browse dialog box in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I have been searching online for information about this but can't seem to find anything of significance but maybe its just because its friday :) but anyways:

I have a project that takes in text files from a server  and reads them but at the moment i just have a drop down menu with a list of files in a specific folder but im wondering is there any way I can open up some sort of browse dialog that allows me to flick through the folder on a server?

Any sugeestions greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try somthing like [that](http://neilang.com/entries/php-explore-your-server-through-a-php-file-browse/) and put it all in jQuery [Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Only something that you make yourself using HTML and CSS. There's no way to open a File Open-like dialog box as you get for choosing a local file that can see the contents of the server, because the client cannot see the contents of the server.